# find element by attribute, set different attribute of the found element

Tags: jquery, find, custom-attributes, attr

this might be confusing to others, as it is to me, but I was wondering if I could use jquery to find an element based on a unique attribute value and then set the value of a different attribute.  Basically i'm trying to make a static page seem dynamic through custom attributes.

Some html is;

```
<div class="Sell" style="width: 47px;"><input type="checkbox" fund-id="1" id="chkSell"     class="_1"/></div>
<div class="Buy" style="width: 47px;"><input type="checkbox" fund-id="1" id="chkBuy"     class="_1"/></div>
<div class="BuySelllbl" style="width: 10px;"><label id="lblBuySell_1" fund-id="1">&nbsp;</label></div>
```

I have set the "fund-id" attribute to "1" to show that all of these are connected for 1 record, subsequent records will be 2, 3, 4 etc..

I have a function where depending on the checkbox that is checked I will display an S for Sell or a B for Buy in the label above.  My function looks like this;

```
$("#chkSell").live('change',function(){
    var y = $(this).attr("class");
    var x = "lblBuySell" + y;
    var fundID = $(this).attr("fund-id");
    //alert(fundID);
    if(this.checked){
        var lbl = $("label").find("[fund-id='" + fundID + "']");
        alert(lbl);
        $(lbl).html("S");
        //$("#" + x).html("S");
        $("#" + x).attr("style","color: red;");
    }else{
        $("#" + x).html("&nbsp;");
    }
});
```

What I want to be able to do is take the fund-id from the checkbox, find the label with the same associated fund-id and set just that labels .html attribute to be an "S" and to be red as you can see below.  Is this possible or am I just out of whack with my thought process?
any help is greatly appreciated.
Thank you,
NickG

Comment: What version of jquery are you using?

Comment: you should use data-attributes then you can make use of jquery's .data to set them and $("label[data-fundid='3']") to find them

Comment: vers: 1.8.3, and @Pete can I use .data to set them after I successfully found the element through my custom attribute?

Comment: @NickG check this article out about using custom attributes: http://html5doctor.com/html5-custom-data-attributes/ and this is the jquery: http://api.jquery.com/data/.  You shouldn't really use unrecognised attributes as some search engines will mark you down for invalid html

Comment: make a fiddle for this http://jsfiddle.net/

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/vrUxt/4/   this is not working as of right now, just a template for it....

Answer (score 1):

You'll want to make use of custom `data-` style attributes to look up the checkbox's corresponding label. In this example, each checkbox has data-fund-id and data-label attributes. When the checkbox is changed, the text of the corect label element is looked up by data-fund-id and (if the checkbox is checked) it's text is set to the data-label value.

**[Working demo](http://jsfiddle.net/mgCTL/)**

**HTML**

```
<div class="Sell" style="width: 47px;">
    <input type="checkbox" data-fund-id="1" id="chkSell" data-label="S" />
</div>
<div class="Buy" style="width: 47px;">
    <input type="checkbox" data-fund-id="1" id="chkBuy" data-label="B" />
</div>

<div id="BuySelllbl" style="width: 10px;">
    <label id="chkSell_lbl" data-fund-id="1">&nbsp;</label>
</div>
```

**jQuery**

```
$(":checkbox").on('change', function () {
    var that = $(this),
        label = $("label[data-fund-id=" + that.data("fund-id") + "]");

    if (this.checked) {
        label.css("color", "red").html(that.data('label')); //the font color should probably just be set in a .css file
    } else {
        label.empty();
    }
});
```

Comment: thanks for your suggestion i'm going to do some messing with it and see, the other reason I don't set the label color via css is because depending on it being a buy or sell i want to change the color and I am using the class property for a different function otherwise i would just set the class property to reflect it

Comment: Also, reading through your code, I don't want to set the checkboxes label to anything, I want to set the label that has the same fund-id as the checkbox that was clicked to the value "S" or "B" depending on the checkbox.  I am trying to find the associated label by using the fund-id that matches that label and the checkbox selected, and then after finding the label with the associated fund-id set the labels HTML attribute to "S" or "B" respectively

Comment: @NickG This code should be updating the label with the same fund-id as the checkbox. Try running the jsFiddle I linked to, I think that's what you are looking for.

Answer (score 0):

I think I figured it out using the following code;

```
$("#chkSell").live('change',function(){
    var y = $(this).attr("class");
    var x = "lblBuySell" + y;
    var fundID = $(this).attr("fund-id");
    //alert(fundID);
    if(this.checked){
        $('label[fund-id="' + fundID + '"]').html("S");
        $('label[fund-id="' + fundID + '"]').attr("style","color: red;");
    }else{
        $("#" + x).html("&nbsp;");
    }
});
```

Comment: This is very similar to the answer I posted, except with this solution you will have to write a handler for each checkbox, instead of one handler for all checkboxes

Comment: you're right, I modeled it off of your code, I think either way with your code i'd have to have the fund-id attribute correct?  That's all I had to do for my code as well, i think they ultimately look for and do the same thing, though yours is cleaner

Comment: I add a fund-id attribute in my answer as well, I just prefix it with `data-`. This is the prefered way to add custom attributes in HTML5. While our answers do accomplish similar things, this answer only addresses one "sell" checkbox, whereas mine will address all checkboxes. Either way, I hope you found a solution that serves you. If you did please accept it so others with the same question will be able to find the answer. Good luck!